# Error propagation when determining drag

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics, error-propagation

I am trying to determine the error of the following formulas and are completely lost.

$k = {mg}/\dot{x}(t)$

$C_D=\frac{2q}{\rho A}$ where $q=mg/\dot{x}(t)^2$

I have values with uncertainties for $x(t)$ and $m$.
How do i move forward when the formulas use $\dot{x}$ and not $x$?

Tldr: How do i apply the rules for error propagation on these formulas?

Answer (score 0):

$\dot{x}(t)=v(t)$ is just the velocity. How do you measure the velocity? Do you measure just the position as a function of time? Like $v(t)=\frac{x(t+dt)-x(t)}{dt}$? If you don't have an error in determining time, the relative error in velocity is given by the regular error propagation in $x$ for the above formula.